# Is there a way to run an app on iOS 12.2 with an outdated version of Xcode and macOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm developing a React Native application that I test and build on a real iPhone 7 using Xcode. However, the iPhone recently automatically updated to iOS 12.2, which requires Xcode version 10.2. The problem is that I can't update Xcode because my Mac is running on High Sierra 10.13.6 and is [too old to get the Mojave update](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201475) (2011).

So the question is: Is there any way I can still use the Mac to run the app on my real device, or am I forced to use the emulators/buy a new Mac from now on? Most importantly, is there I way I can still get the Mojave update on my old Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the support files that you want from this [repo](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport)

Close your xcode, right click on xcode ->Show Package Contents->Contents->Developer->Platforms->iPhoneOS.platform->DeviceSupport, and unzip your file there.

Restart xcode and voilà, your device is supported.

check [this](https://ighibli.github.io/2017/03/28/Could-not-locate-device-support-files/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

There is some trick for you to [install Mojavae](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/update-macos-old-mac-3654960/) and so Xcode 10.2.

I hope that can help you, and think to deactivate the auto update.